# Magento 1.9, Order email found in core_email_queue, but not sent out

Tags: magento-1.9, crontab, email-scheduler

I have Magento 1.9 website, and the order emails have always been working. But about just a few days a ago I noticed that the order confirmation emails are not sent out to customers.

I have set cronjob up like this,

```
*/5 * * * * /opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php /var/www/public_html/webshop/cron.php > /dev/null
```

I have installed AOE scehduler, and it looks like this,
[image]

And in table `cron_schedule`, every thing also looks as usual.

[image]

And this is how the table `core_email_queue` looks like,

[image]

I have tried to clear the table `cron_schedule`, but it didn't help. And I haven't changed any setup in Magento. What more can I diagnose with?